# How can I advance a page without losing my column position?

Tags: cursor-movement, scrolling

I like using <kbd>Ctrl-f</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-b</kbd> to "page-up" and "page-down", but I was wondering if there was a way to do that without losing my current position in a row? For example, I like to work with tab-delimited files and scroll up and down columns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply add `set nostartofline` to your `vimrc`.

See `:help 'startofline'`.